# How to wait a method in a new class for code reuse. selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I am new to c# Selenium automation.

Can anyone teach me how to create a new method under new class or extend method so that i can re use this code.

```
new WebDriverWait(PropertiesCollection.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(12))
              .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("ctl00_Cont_frame")));
```

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(xpath or css")));

Comment: Oh you mean i can reuse the wait command?

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(1st xpath element")));

*** Other operation **** 

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(Another xpath element")));

*** Other operation **** 

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(Another xpath element")));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh you want to reuse a method. PAge object model is very helpful for it. Suppose your main class is A and you want to make some common reusable methods then, create a class B and put that method there. Here , put wait method in class B and then call it from class a whenever you need to use.

See my below example,

My main test case:

```
SignInPage.WaitForElementTobeVisible(driver, By.cssSelector("input[id='Passwd'][type='password']"));
```

it will call this class

```
public class SignInPage {

public void WaitForElementTobeVisible(WebDriver driver, By by) {
    WebUtils.WaitVisibilityOfElement(driver, by);
  }
}
```

And finally this will call

```
public class WebUtils {

public static void WaitVisibilityOfElement(WebDriver driver, By by) {

WebDriverWait Wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
  }
}
```

Hope this solves your query.
Reply to me for further query :-) 
Happy learning

Comment: If you like my answer. Just check the tick mark or do the upvote. IT will help me :-) Thank you. :-)